# Explode values in a word/string with Regex

Tags: php, regex

i have this sample string and i want to explode the day,month,hour,minutes,(am/pm) wih regex:

```
SunDec 16 00:00am
```

Using this:

```
(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\d+)\:(\d+)(..)
```

But it gives me:

```
Array
(
    [0] => SunDec 16 00:00am
    [1] => SunDec
    [2] => 16
    [3] => 00
    [4] => 00
    [5] => am
)
```

I cant figure it out..Can i explode SubDec into two?

Comment: I don't get it; isn't this what you wanted?  Just disregard the first two values and you are in business.

Comment: He can't figure how to explode "SunDec" into Sun and Dec

Comment: If the format is always 3+3 letters(Sun+Dec, Mon+Mar, etc.), than just split those by their length in two.

Comment: hey anybody needs it in js without regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
$str = 'SunDec 16 00:00am';

preg_match('/([A-Z]{1}\w+)([A-Z]{1}\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\d+):(\d+)(..)/', $str, $ret);

print_r($ret);
```

Comment: +1, but those `{1}` "quantifiers" aren't doing anything useful.

Comment: Yes! You are right, thx. We can drop the `{1}` "quantifiers".:)

Answer (score 1):

If your string is always going to follow that example you can use this:

```
$string = 'SunDec 16 00:00am';
$pattern = '!([a-zA-Z]{3})([a-zA-Z]{3})\s+(\w+)\s+(\d+)\:(\d+)(..)!';
preg_match($pattern, $string, $chunks);
print_r($chunks);
```

Which outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => SunDec 16 00:00am
    [1] => Sun
    [2] => Dec
    [3] => 16
    [4] => 00
    [5] => 00
    [6] => am
)
```

You could use this pattern too which is slightly smaller

```
'!([a-z]{3})([a-z]{3})\s+(\w+)\s+(\d+)\:(\d+)(..)!i'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this Regular Expression, This might help you

```
([A-Z][a-z]+)+\s(\d+)?\s?(\d+)\:(\d+)([a-z]+)
```